# ttk.Treeview - Can't change row height

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I'm using `ttkcalendar.py` which can be found [in this link.](https://code.google.com/p/python-ttk/source/browse/trunk/pyttk-samples/ttkcalendar.py?r=27)

I've adapted it for use in `Python 3.3`

Basically what i'm trying to do is enter this calendar widget into my Tkinter application, which works fine and there's no problems there.

The problems I wish to overcome are:

1. How do I change the font size of the calendar (Month,Days & Dates) - **Completed**
2. How do I change the selected date so it goes `bold`.  - **Completed**
3. How can I change the height of the rows in the `treeview` as in prevoius attempts font size can be increased but the row height does not increase with font size.  - **STILL AWAITING HELP**

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1:**

Find below the code for the whole program:

```
import calendar
import tkinter as Tkinter
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from tkinter import ttk                             #Imports ttk Module

def get_calendar(locale, fwday):
    #Instantiate Proper Calendar Class
    if locale is None:
        return calendar.TextCalendar(fwday)
    else:
        return calendar.LocaleTextCalendar(fwday, locale)

class Calendar(ttk.Frame):
    datetime = calendar.datetime.datetime
    timedelta = calendar.datetime.timedelta

    def __init__(self, master=None, **kw):
        """
        WIDGET-SPECIFIC OPTIONS

            locale, firstweekday, year, month, selectbackground,
            selectforeground
        """
        #Remove Custom Options From kw BEFORE Initializating ttk.Frame
        fwday = kw.pop('firstweekday', calendar.MONDAY)
        year = kw.pop('year', self.datetime.now().year)
        month = kw.pop('month', self.datetime.now().month)
        locale = kw.pop('locale', None)
        sel_bg = kw.pop('selectbackground', '#EEEEEE')
        sel_fg = kw.pop('selectforeground', '#B6333B')

        self._date = self.datetime(year, month, 1)
        self._selection = None                          #No Date Selected

        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kw)

        self._cal = get_calendar(locale, fwday)

        self.__setup_styles()                           #Creates Custom Styles
        self.__place_widgets()                          #Pack/Grid Used Widgets
        self.__config_calendar()                        #Adjust Calendar Columns & Setup Tags
        #Configure a Canvas & Proper Bindings for Selecting Dates
        self.__setup_selection(sel_bg, sel_fg)

        #Store Item ids - Used for Insertion Later On
        self._items = [self._calendar.insert('', 'end', values='')
                            for _ in range(6)]
        #Insert Dates in the Currently Empty Calendar
        self._build_calendar()

        #Set Minimal Size for Widget
        self._calendar.bind('<Map>', self.__minsize)

    def __setitem__(self, item, value):
        if item in ('year', 'month'):
            raise AttributeError("attribute '%s' is not writeable" % item)
        elif item == 'selectbackground':
            self._canvas['background'] = value
        elif item == 'selectforeground':
            self._canvas.itemconfigure(self._canvas.text, item=value)
        else:
            ttk.Frame.__setitem__(self, item, value)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if item in ('year', 'month'):
            return getattr(self._date, item)
        elif item == 'selectbackground':
            return self._canvas['background']
        elif item == 'selectforeground':
            return self._canvas.itemcget(self._canvas.text, 'fill')
        else:
            r = ttk.tclobjs_to_py({item: ttk.Frame.__getitem__(self, item)})
            return r[item]

    def __setup_styles(self):
        #CUSTOM ttk Styles
        style = ttk.Style(self.master)
        arrow_layout = lambda dir: (
            [('Button.focus', {'children': [('Button.%sarrow' % dir, None)]})]
        )
        style.layout('L.TButton', arrow_layout('left'))
        style.layout('R.TButton', arrow_layout('right'))

    def __place_widgets(self):
        #Header Frame & Widgets
        hframe = ttk.Frame(self)
        lbtn = ttk.Button(hframe, style='L.TButton', command=self._prev_month)
        rbtn = ttk.Button(hframe, style='R.TButton', command=self._next_month)
        self._header = ttk.Label(hframe, width=15, anchor='center', font='Arial 20')
        #Main Calendar
        self._calendar = ttk.Treeview(show='', selectmode='none', height='6')
        #Pack The Widgets
        hframe.pack(in_=self, side='top', pady=4, anchor='center')
        lbtn.grid(in_=hframe)
        self._header.grid(in_=hframe, column=1, row=0, padx=12)
        rbtn.grid(in_=hframe, column=2, row=0)
        self._calendar.pack(in_=self, expand=1, fill='both', side='bottom')

    def __config_calendar(self):
        cols = self._cal.formatweekheader(3).split()
        self._calendar['columns'] = cols
        self._calendar.tag_configure('header', background='grey90', font='Arial 20')
        self._calendar.insert('', 'end', values=cols, tag=('header', 'dayFont'))
        #Change Font of dayFont TAG
        self._calendar.tag_configure('dayFont', font='Arial 20')
        #Adjust Column Widths
        font = tkFont.Font(size=20)
        maxwidth = max(font.measure(col) for col in cols)
        for col in cols:
            self._calendar.column(col, width=maxwidth, minwidth=maxwidth, anchor='c')

    def __setup_selection(self, sel_bg, sel_fg):
        self._font = tkFont.Font()
        canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(self._calendar, background=sel_bg, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self._canvas = canvas
        canvas.text = canvas.create_text(0, 0, fill=sel_fg, anchor='c')

        canvas.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', lambda evt: canvas.place_forget())
        self._calendar.bind('<Configure>', lambda evt: canvas.place_forget())
        self._calendar.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self._pressed)

    def __minsize(self, evt):
        width, height = self._calendar.master.geometry().split('x')
        height = height[:height.index('+')]
        self._calendar.master.minsize(width, height)

    def _build_calendar(self):
        year, month = self._date.year, self._date.month

        #Update Header Text (Month, YEAR)
        header = self._cal.formatmonthname(year, month, 0)
        self._header['text'] = header.title()

        #Update Calendar Showing Dates
        cal = self._cal.monthdayscalendar(year, month)

        for indx, item in enumerate(self._items):
            week = cal[indx] if indx < len(cal) else []
            fmt_week = [('%02d' % day) if day else '' for day in week]
            self._calendar.item(item, values=fmt_week, tag='bodyFont')
            self._calendar.tag_configure('bodyFont', font='Arial 10')        


    def _show_selection(self, text, bbox): #SELECTION FONT
        """Configure canvas for a new selection."""
        x, y, width, height = bbox

        textw = self._font.measure(text)

        canvas = self._canvas
        canvas.configure(width=width, height=height)
        canvas.coords(canvas.text, width - textw, height / 2 - 1)
        canvas.itemconfigure(canvas.text, text=text, font='Arial 15 bold')
        canvas.place(in_=self._calendar, x=x, y=y)

    #Callbacks

    def _pressed(self, evt):
        """Clicked somewhere in the calendar."""
        x, y, widget = evt.x, evt.y, evt.widget
        item = widget.identify_row(y)
        column = widget.identify_column(x)

        if not column or not item in self._items:       #Clicked in the Weekdays Row or Just Outside The Columns
            return

        item_values = widget.item(item)['values']
        if not len(item_values):                        #Row is Empty For This Month
            return

        text = item_values[int(column[1]) - 1]
        if not text:                                    #Date is Empty
            return

        bbox = widget.bbox(item, column)
        if not bbox:                                    #Calendar is not Visible Yet
            return

        #Update & Then Show Selection
        text = '%02d' % text
        self._selection = (text, item, column)
        self._show_selection(text, bbox)

    def _prev_month(self):
        """Updated calendar to show the previous month."""
        self._canvas.place_forget()

        self._date = self._date - self.timedelta(days=1)
        self._date = self.datetime(self._date.year, self._date.month, 1)
        #Reconstruct Calendar
        self._build_calendar()

    def _next_month(self):
        """Update calendar to show the next month."""
        self._canvas.place_forget()

        year, month = self._date.year, self._date.month
        self._date = self._date + self.timedelta(
            days=calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1] + 1)
        self._date = self.datetime(self._date.year, self._date.month, 1)

        self._build_calendar() 

    #Properties
    #-----------------------------------------------------

    @property
    def selection(self):
        """Return a datetime representing the current selected date."""
        if not self._selection:
            return None

        year, month = self._date.year, self._date.month
        return self.datetime(year, month, int(self._selection[0]))

#----------------------------------
```

**EDIT 2:**

How can I change the `relief` of the `Treeview`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Perhaps like you, I expected lines to expand as necessary.  But I confirmed the problem with the code below, with the solution (the two style lines) omitted.  When I could not find the solution [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Treeview.html) and the corresponding Style page, I googled and found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.tcl/dv2urOQTeUA).  Scroll down to Emiliano's answer, and some of the following (there is also an indent option).

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x200')
style = ttk.Style(root)
style.configure('Treeview', rowheight=40)  #SOLUTION
tree = ttk.Treeview(root)
tree.insert('', 0, text='Line 1 of many XXX', tags='T')
tree.insert('', 1, text='Line 2 of many XXX', tags='T')
tree.insert('', 2, text='Line 3 of many XXX', tags='T')
tree.column('#0', stretch=True)
tree.tag_configure('T', font='Arial 20')
tree.pack(fill='x')
```

The above, with the answer omitted, is an example of minimal code that exhibits the problem. This is the sort of thing to post!

**EDIT 1:**

To make the Calendar widget properly importable and usable in another application, it should use a custom style, so its style does not affect any other treeviews in the app.

```
style.configure('Calendar.Treeview', rowheight=40)
tree = ttk.Treeview(root, style='Calendar.Treeview')
```

**EDIT 2:**

I am just learning about ttk styles myself.  To answer your relief question, I went to this [style doc](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-layouts.html) and tried the following in Idle's Shell after running the above, with the two modifications in Edit 1.

```
>>> style.layout('Calendar.Treeview')
[('Treeview.field', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children': [('Treeview.padding',
{'sticky': 'nswe', 'children': [('Treeview.treearea', {'sticky': 'nswe'})]})], 'border': '1'})]
>>> style.element_options('Calendar.Treeview.border')
('-relief',)
>>> style.lookup('Calendar.Treeview.border', 'relief')
''
>>> style.configure('Calendar.Treeview.border', relief='raised')
{}
```

I do not see any border nor did not see any effect of the setting.  Perhaps relief applies to borders between columns.  I don't know.  (Note that changing rowheight is immediately available, so configuration is 'live'.)

Comment: Thanks Terry! Have spent hours trying to figure it out with no avail. I have one small question to add: How can I change the relief of the Treeview? Is it possible?

Comment: Great answers , great people.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy I have a project with 3 different treeviews, and I have tried to use :
`style = ttk.Style(root)`
`style.configure('Treeview', rowheight=40)`

But then it changes the row height for all treeviews , not for the treeview that I wanted. I have tried to change the `root` but it didnt work, can you please help me with this?

Comment: @AleksandarBeat I have not worked with styles for 3 years.  But I expect configuring 'Treeview' should change all.  See Edit 1 about using a custom style for the Treeview you want to customize.

Answer (score 5):

I found that the Tkinter Font object has a metrics() method, that gives its height as "linespace". That allows the row height to be scaled dynamically:

```
try:
    from tkinter.font import Font
    from tkinter.ttk import Style, Treeview
    from tkinter import *         
except:
    from tkFont import Font
    from ttk import Style, Treeview
    from Tkinter import *

font=Font(family='Arial', size=20)
font.metrics()
#output: {'ascent': 31, 'descent': 7, 'linespace': 38, 'fixed': 0}
```

With that, you can get the font height with:

```
font.metrics()['linespace']
#output: 38
```

Then use it to set the rowheight in your Treeview widget:

```
fontheight=font.metrics()['linespace']

style=Style()
style.configure('Calendar.Treeview', font=font, rowheight=fontheight)   

tree=Treeview(style='Calendar.Treeview')
```

Changing the font object parameters comfortably updates the Treeview widget, but the rowheight doesn't get updated, and needs to be redone. So for example, scaling the font size with a keyboard shortcut may look like this:

```
def scaleup(event):
    font['size']+=1
    style.configure('Calendar.Treeview', rowheight=font.metrics()['linespace'])

def scaledown(event):
    font['size']-=1
    style.configure('Calendar.Treeview', rowheight=font.metrics()['linespace'])

tree.bind('<Control-equal>', scaleup)
tree.bind('<Control-minus>', scaledown)
```

I actually wanted to do the same  with Control-MouseWheel, but didn't figure out the behavior yet (Would be glad to hear how that works).

Hope this comes handy.

Comment: Wonderful!! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: I realize this is 2 years later, but I had the same question, and figure others might also end up here and need to go there next. This is the best discussion I've seen of that so far. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355902/tkinter-binding-mousewheel-to-scrollbar

Answer (score 1):

> How can I change the height of the rows in the treeview as in prevoius attempts font size can be increased but the row height does not increase with font size. - STILL AWAITING HELP

In case you are still awaiting help on this one, there *is* a [way](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.tcl/dv2urOQTeUA) to change the row height, though that google groups thread says that it isn't officially supported by Tk:

```
#apply any configuration options
ttk.Style().configure('Treeview',rowheight=30)
```