# Is there a way to change height of tkinter Treeview heading?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, treeview

I got a problem with changing the height of the `Treeview.heading`. I have found some answers about the dimensions of `Treeview.column`, but when I access `Treeview.heading` in the documentation, there is not a single word about changing the height of the heading dynamically when the text doesn't fit (and wrapping it) or even just hard-coding height of the heading in pixels.
I don't have to split the text to two rows, but when I just keep it that long the whole table (as it has many entries) takes up the whole screen. I want to keep it smaller, therefore I need to split longer entries.

Here is how it looks like:

[image: As it can be seen, the text is not fully visible in Treeview heading]

Comment: Yeah that is what I thought too - if you can resize the width, why no height. But it seems that part is missing. Or I am just terribly blind.
EDIT: The 'size' is the reference name of the column that you want to set the heading in (these names can be set in `Treeview.columns`; you can also use numbers) and the `text` is the string that should appear in it. So it's not it.

Comment: Check out this post: [ttk.Treeview - Can't change row height](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26962663/7475225). It looks like a good start.

Comment: This allows changing the height of the rows, but not the heading, unfortunately.

Comment: The more I dig in the more I find I can edit in the header but non of the editable style layout has a height field for header... It may not be possible in this case. My guess is the height is hard coded and does not have a variable we can change.

Answer (score 2):

I can't find any documentation to verify this but it looks like the height of the heading is determined by the heading in the first column.

**Reproducing the problem**

```
col_list = ('Name', 'Three\nLine\nHeader', 'Two\nline')
tree = Treeview(parent, columns=col_list[1:])
ix = -1
for col in col_list:
    ix += 1
    tree.heading(f'#{ix}', text=col)
```

**The fix**

```
col_list = ('Name\n\n', 'Three\nLine\nHeader', 'Two\nline')
```

or, if you want to make it look prettier

```
col_list = ('\nName\n', 'Three\nLine\nHeader', 'Two\nline')
```

The only problem is I haven't figured out how to centre the heading on a two line header

**Edit**

The newlines work if it is the top level window but not if it is a dialog.  Another way of doing this is to set the style.  I've got no idea why this works.

```
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure('Treeview.Heading', foreground='black')
```

Comment: This works (the toplevel version), but with a clarification: you didn't name your first column (by doing col_list[1:]). You can cheat by using all of your columns, then adding an extra line outside the for loop:

`tree.heading('#0', text='\n\n')`

Answer (score 0):

you can use font size to increase the header height for sometimes;

[image]

```
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure('Treeview.Heading', foreground='black', background='white', font=('Arial',25),)
```

Answer (score 0):

Scrolledtreeview1.heading("#0", text="\n\n",anchor="center")

use \n in heading #0 text as many lines you want.