# Unable to wrap text in heading - tkinter Treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I tried changing the style of tkinter Treeview through rowheight parameter. But it is only affecting rows other than heading. THe documentation offers no hope.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59970241/is-there-a-way-to-change-height-of-tkinter-treeview-heading

Comment: Hey thanks, but unfortunately this is not working, Adding the \n makes only one line appear

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can see better what your problem is. Also it is not clear if you want to manually set the height of the heading or wrap it dynamically.