# Tkinter bind <Shift-MouseWheel> to horizontal scroll

Tags: python, user-interface, events, scroll, tkinter

I have a text widget with a horizontal and vertical scroll bar. I would like to be able to scroll up and down normally, and scroll side to side while holding shift. I can't figure out what to bind the `<Shift-MouseWheel>` event to, or what the callback ought to be. Here's a code snippet of the mainWindow(Tk.TopLevel)'s `__init__():`

```
    # console text
    self.yScroll = Tk.Scrollbar(self)
    self.yScroll.pack(side=Tk.RIGHT, fill=Tk.Y)
    self.xScroll = Tk.Scrollbar(self)
    self.xScroll.pack(side=Tk.BOTTOM, fill=Tk.X)
    self.log = Tk.Text(self,
                       wrap=Tk.NONE,
                       width=80,
                       height=24,
                       yscrollcommand=self.yScroll.set,
                       xscrollcommand=self.xScroll.set)
    self.log.pack()
    self.yScroll.config(command=self.log.yview)
    self.xScroll.config(command=self.log.xview, orient=Tk.HORIZONTAL)

    # shift scroll binding
    self.bind('<Shift-MouseWheel>', ) # what do I need here?
```

I have successfully bound the shift-scroll to simple print functions, etc. but I'm not sure how to bind it to the text box scrolling.

Comment: Are you saying you don't know how to call the `xview` command of the widget?

Comment: more or less... I'm not sure where to pass the event and make it actually scroll the window. Tried: `self.bind('<Shift-MouseWheel>', self.log.xview)` got: `TclError: bad option "<Tkinter.Event instance at 0x0572C1E8>": must be moveto or scroll`

Comment: If you want to enable regular horizontal scrolling, too, or if you get the error I got with `(event.delta/120)` as an argument, even though that still works, you might check out this related q/a: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46194948/what-are-the-tkinter-events-for-horizontal-edge-scrolling-in-linux

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have the binding call your own function, and then have that function call the [xview_scroll](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.xview_scroll-method) method of the widget:

```
self.bind('<Shift-MouseWheel>', self.scrollHorizontally) 
...

def scrollHorizontally(self, event):
    self.log.xview_scroll((event.delta/120), "units")
```

You may need to adjust the number of units (or "pages") you want to scroll with each click of the wheel.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17457843/7432) has more information about platform differences with respect to the `delta` attribute of the event.