# Python (3.10) TKinter: horizontal scrolling on touchpad (laptop)

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, touchpad

## Using Python 3.10 and TKinter Library

I had an issue with touchpad horizontal scrolling being received as vertical scrolling, searched online a fix, I did find a potential fix using StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46194948/what-are-the-tkinter-events-for-horizontal-edge-scrolling-in-linux/46194949#46194949). However, for windows, or maybe just my laptop it didn't work. I then checked what I was allowed to do with the event object and 'state' existed.

**Using print(event.state) you can figure out what value your horizontal scroll and vertical are**. Using that you can fix your code to allow horizontal and vertical scrolling on a touchpad. Hope you enjoy.
(I don't have enough karma for literally anything, and this is a **real** solution, but not a question unfortunately, so hopefully its okay.)

```
# Bind canvas to scrollbar
        self.canvas.config(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
        self.canvas.config(xscrollcommand=self.horizontal_scrollbar.set)
        self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all")))
        self.canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self.on_mousewheel)

# on_mousewheel function below:

def on_mousewheel(self, event):
        # Check if Control key is held down
        if event.state & 0x4:
            # Horizontal scrolling
            self.canvas.xview_scroll(int(-1 * (event.delta / 80)), "units")
        else:
            # Vertical + Horizontal scrolling
            if event.state == 9:
                self.canvas.xview_scroll(int(-1 * (event.delta / 80)), "units")
            elif event.state == 8:
                self.canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1 * (event.delta / 100)), "units")
```

Tried to allow horizontal scrolling using a touchpad on a laptop, couldn't at first, it was received as vertical scrolling regardless of moving my hands left to right. Found a potential solution that didn't work, it made me think and I figured out a solution. This post is to inform people on how to find vertical and horizontal scrolling states for Python 3.10 with the TKinter library.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, I'm glad you've solved the problem! However if you want to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), you should post a separate answer. Putting the answer inside the question is against the SO guidelines. See [answer] for more information on writing answers.

Comment: Good point, I didn't think of that at the time, I assumed the reputation requirements were also included in your own posts tbh. I'm honestly surprised to hear that its against the guidelines of Stack Overflow too. I also just read the portion you linked to 'answer your own question' in which I actually don't believe I would've been able to due to my lack of reputation, I only would've been able to do so AFTER (depending on how much you get from posting) I posted said question, and then waited for my reputation to go up from upvotes/etc. Thank you for mentioning this though, I appreciate it!