# Scrolling multiple Tkinter listboxes together using mouse wheel and scrollbar

Tags: tkinter, listbox

I am quite new to Tkinter and I had tried to create a program for multiple Tkinter Listbox that scrolls together using a single scrollbar and mouse wheel. When I run the program and start scrolling the left Listbox using my mouse wheel, the right Listbox doesn't scroll with it. However, when I start scrolling the right Listbox using the mouse wheel, the left Listbox scrolls with it. I couldn't find the error.

How do I fix the program so that when I start scrolling using my mouse wheel on either left or right Listbox, both Listbox will scroll together?

```
try:
    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import *


class MultipleScrollingListbox(Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title('Scrolling Multiple Listboxes')

        self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical')

        self.list1 = Listbox(self, width = 40, height = 10, yscrollcommand = self.yscroll1)
        self.list1.grid(row = 2, sticky = W)

        self.list2 = Listbox(self, width = 40, height = 10, yscrollcommand = self.yscroll1)
        self.list2.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = E)

        self.scrollbar.config(command=self.yview)
        self.scrollbar.grid(row = 2, column = 2, sticky = "nsw")

        #filling the listboxes with stuff

        for x in range(30):
            self.list1.insert('end', "  " + str(x))
            self.list2.insert('end', "  " + str(x))


    #The part where both Listbox scrolls together when scrolled 

    def yscroll1(self, *args):
        if self.list2.yview() != self.list1.yview():
            self.list2.yview_moveto(args[0])
        self.scrollbar.set(*args)

    def yscroll2(self, *args):
        if self.list1.yview() != self.list2.yview():
            self.list1.yview_moveto(args[0])
        self.scrollbar.set(*args)

    def yview(self, *args):
        self.list1.yview(*args)
        self.list2.yview(*args)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = MultipleScrollingListbox()
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind `MouseWheel` event to your root window which will allow you to scroll anywhere. If you don't want to bind to root window, you can also specify the widgets you want.

```
try:
    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import *


class MultipleScrollingListbox(Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)

        ... 

        self.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self.mousewheel)

        ...

    def mousewheel(self, event):
        self.list1.yview_scroll(-1 * int(event.delta / 120), "units")
        self.list2.yview_scroll(-1 * int(event.delta / 120), "units")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = MultipleScrollingListbox()
    root.mainloop()
```

For a more detailed explanation on why you need to do a `delta/120`, you can read up the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355902/python-tkinter-binding-mousewheel-to-scrollbar).