# Is there any way to bind mouse scroll wheel's downward motion to a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, mousewheel

I have created these two functions :The first *increases* the `extent` value of arc and the other *decreases* it. I tried binding them resp. to `<MouseWheel>` and `<ShiftMouseWheel>`. But it doesn't work.

```
def angle_up(event= None):
    global extent
    extent += 2

def angle_dn(event= None):
    global extent
    extent -= 2
```

Then I bound them to mouse events:

```
def draw_arc(event=None):
    frame.bind('<MouseWheel>',angle_up)
    frame.bind('<Shift-MouseWheel>', angle_dn)
```

Even if I scroll the wheel down the `angle_dn` function doesn't gets called, instead the `angle_up` function gets called.

Is there any way to bind mousewheel upwards motion to a separate function and downwards movement of wheel to a separate function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python tkinter binding mousewheel to scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17457843/7414759)

Comment: No , I've already read that one.If we bind MouseWheel to scrollbar that different i.e., it goes down on downwards motion of scrollwheel and vice versa.As I stated above, in case of binding it to normal functions it behave differently. My struggle is to bind different functions to wheel movement depending on its direction upwards & downwards.

Comment: Read up on [Events and Bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm), Section **Event Attributes** using `event.num` to distinguish between **up** and **down**. Read the last answer of the given link.

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter's `event` has an attribute `delta` which returns a positive integer when scrollwheel moves up and vice versa.
Instead of creating two separate functions ,create a new function `angle` having an argument `event`.

```
def angle(event):
    if event.delta > 0:
        extent += 1
    elif event.delta < 0:
        extent -= 1
```

Bind this function to `<MouseWheel>` event.

```
cavas.bind("<MouseWheel>" , angle)
```

Moving ScrollWheel upwards will increment `extent` and downwards motion will decrement `extent`