# Unable to Scroll Frame using Mouse Wheel & Adding Horizontal Scrollbar

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I'm Unable to Scroll My Frame using Mouse Wheel.
Can anyone tell me how can i Scroll Frame using mouse Wheel Vertically
& also tell me how to add a horizontal Scrollbar to same Frame and Scroll it using Shift+Mousewheel.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.tix import *

root = Tk()
root.wm_title('DEMO SCROLL')
frame = Frame(width="500",height="500")
frame.pack()
swin = ScrolledWindow(frame, width=500, height=500)
swin.pack()
win = swin.window
for i in range(50):
    Label(win,text="hello").pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux?

Comment: You can use `MouseWheel` on the vertical scrollbar instead on the frame.  The horizontal scrollbar will be shown if you put many labels in a row.  Also you can use `Shift+MouseWheel` on the horizontal scrollbar.

Answer (score 5):

You can't scroll `<tkinter.Frame>` so we use a dummy canvas. We put the frame inside the canvas so that when we scroll the canvas it looks like we are scrolling the frame. We also have to bind to the user scrolling and the scrollbar being changed.

If you want it as a class:

```py
import tkinter as tk


FIT_WIDTH = "fit_width"
FIT_HEIGHT = "fit_height"


class ScrollableFrame(tk.Frame):
    """
    There is no way to scroll <tkinter.Frame> so we are
    going to create a canvas and place the frame there.
    Scrolling the canvas will give the illusion of scrolling
    the frame
    Partly taken from:
        https://blog.tecladocode.com/tkinter-scrollable-frames/
        https://stackoverflow.com/a/17457843/11106801
    master_frame---------------------------------------------------------
    | dummy_canvas-----------------------------------------  y_scroll--  |
    | | self---------------------------------------------  | |         | |
    | | |                                                | | |         | |
    | | |                                                | | |         | |
    | | |                                                | | |         | |
    | |  ------------------------------------------------  | |         | |
    |  ----------------------------------------------------   ---------  |
    | x_scroll---------------------------------------------              |
    | |                                                    |             |
    |  ----------------------------------------------------              |
     --------------------------------------------------------------------
    """
    def __init__(self, master=None, scroll_speed:int=2, hscroll:bool=False,
                 vscroll:bool=True, bd:int=0, scrollbar_kwargs={},
                 bg="#f0f0ed", **kwargs):
        assert isinstance(scroll_speed, int), "`scroll_speed` must be an int"
        self.scroll_speed = scroll_speed

        self.master_frame = tk.Frame(master, bd=bd, bg=bg)
        self.master_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.master_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.dummy_canvas = tk.Canvas(self.master_frame, highlightthickness=0,
                                      bd=0, bg=bg, **kwargs)
        super().__init__(self.dummy_canvas, bg=bg)

        # Create the 2 scrollbars
        if vscroll:
            self.v_scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.master_frame,
                                            orient="vertical",
                                            command=self.dummy_canvas.yview,
                                            **scrollbar_kwargs)
            self.v_scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="news")
            self.dummy_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.v_scrollbar.set)
        if hscroll:
            self.h_scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.master_frame,
                                            orient="horizontal",
                                            command=self.dummy_canvas.xview,
                                            **scrollbar_kwargs)
            self.h_scrollbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="news")
            self.dummy_canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self.h_scrollbar.set)

        # Bind to the mousewheel scrolling
        self.dummy_canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self.scrolling_windows,
                                   add=True)
        self.dummy_canvas.bind_all("<Button-4>", self.scrolling_linux, add=True)
        self.dummy_canvas.bind_all("<Button-5>", self.scrolling_linux, add=True)
        self.bind("<Configure>", self.scrollbar_scrolling, add=True)

        # Place `self` inside `dummy_canvas`
        self.dummy_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self, anchor="nw")
        # Place `dummy_canvas` inside `master_frame`
        self.dummy_canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")

        self.pack = self.master_frame.pack
        self.grid = self.master_frame.grid
        self.place = self.master_frame.place
        self.pack_forget = self.master_frame.pack_forget
        self.grid_forget = self.master_frame.grid_forget
        self.place_forget = self.master_frame.place_forget

    def scrolling_windows(self, event:tk.Event) -> None:
        assert event.delta != 0, "On Windows, `event.delta` should never be 0"
        y_steps = int(-event.delta/abs(event.delta)*self.scroll_speed)
        self.dummy_canvas.yview_scroll(y_steps, "units")

    def scrolling_linux(self, event:tk.Event) -> None:
        y_steps = self.scroll_speed
        if event.num == 4:
            y_steps *= -1
        self.dummy_canvas.yview_scroll(y_steps, "units")

    def scrollbar_scrolling(self, event:tk.Event) -> None:
        region = list(self.dummy_canvas.bbox("all"))
        region[2] = max(self.dummy_canvas.winfo_width(), region[2])
        region[3] = max(self.dummy_canvas.winfo_height(), region[3])
        self.dummy_canvas.configure(scrollregion=region)

    def resize(self, fit:str=None, height:int=None, width:int=None) -> None:
        """
        Resizes the frame to fit the widgets inside. You must either
        specify (the `fit`) or (the `height` or/and the `width`) parameter.
        Parameters:
            fit:str       `fit` can be either `FIT_WIDTH` or `FIT_HEIGHT`.
                          `FIT_WIDTH` makes sure that the frame's width can
                           fit all of the widgets. `FIT_HEIGHT` is simmilar
            height:int     specifies the height of the frame in pixels
            width:int      specifies the width of the frame in pixels
        To do:
            ALWAYS_FIT_WIDTH
            ALWAYS_FIT_HEIGHT
        """
        if height is not None:
            self.dummy_canvas.config(height=height)
        if width is not None:
            self.dummy_canvas.config(width=width)
        if fit == FIT_WIDTH:
            super().update()
            self.dummy_canvas.config(width=super().winfo_width())
        elif fit == FIT_HEIGHT:
            super().update()
            self.dummy_canvas.config(height=super().winfo_height())
        else:
            raise ValueError("Unknow value for the `fit` parameter.")
    fit = resize


# Example 1
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    frame = ScrollableFrame(root, width=300, height=200, hscroll=True, vscroll=True)
    frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

    # Add the widgets in the main diagonal to see the horizontal and
    # vertical scrolling
    for i in range(51):
        label = tk.Label(frame, text=i, anchor="w")
        label.grid(row=i, column=i)

    root.mainloop()


# Example 2
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    frame = ScrollableFrame(root, height=200, hscroll=False, vscroll=True)
    frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

    for i in range(51):
        label = tk.Label(frame, text=f"Label number {i}")
        label.pack(anchor="w")

    # Force the frame to resize to fit all of the widgets:
    frame.resize(FIT_WIDTH)

    root.mainloop()
```