# Making Entry widget move with a scrollbar using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I can use Listbox to move text with the scrollbar, but I wanted to have moving entry boxes beside it to fill information in. Is it possible to link entry boxes to the scrollbar?

Text ___________

text2 __________

Comment: Try using the class I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66215091/11106801). It is a `ScrollableFrame` class that allows you to place your widgets inside it and it will automatically add the scrollbar

Comment: Are you wanting to scroll the text horizontally within the widget, or are you wanting the widgets to move up and down in sync with a listbox?

Comment: You could use `Text` and add widget to it.

Comment: Move vertically

Comment: @CoolCloud what do you mean by using Text?

Comment: `Text` has a `window_create()` method to create windows. Read [Here](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/text-window.html)