# How can I create buttons and labels in a canvas widget and make the whole set of widgets in the canvas scrollable?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-layout

How can I create buttons and labels in a canvas widget and make the whole set of widgets in the canvas scrollable?

I came across a `_create()` option in my IDE but I'm not sure how to use it. I tried entering Button for `itemType` but it didn't work.
I tried `create_window()` but I'm not sure how to use it either.

My question is not how to use a loop and add the buttons, but how can I create widgets and place them in a canvas, but scrollable? Also is there a `_create()`? If yes, is there any way to create widgets using it?

Comment: First of all, you need to make the canvas the parent of the widget then instead of calling `.pack`/`.grid`/`.place` use `<tk.Canvas>.create_window(<x>, <y>, window=<widget>, anchor=<anchor>)`. For more info look [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20201108093851/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_window-method). Also if you just want a scrollable frame use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66215091/11106801)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to create buttons and labels in a canvas widget and make the whole set of widgets in the canvas scrollable?

You have two choices:

- use the canvas method `create_window` to add the buttons and labels to the canvas at specific coordinates
- use the canvas method `create_window` to add a frame to the canvas, and then put your buttons and labels inside of the frame using `pack` or `grid` or `place`.

You then have to make sure you configure the `scrollregion` of the canvas to be large enough to include the widgets.

> I came across a _create() option in my IDE but I'm not sure how to use it.

The following example shows how to use `create_window` to add a button to a canvas. The procedure is the same for any type of widget.

```
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

the_button = tk.Button(canvas, text="Click me", ...)
canvas.create_window(10, 10, window=the_button, anchor="nw")
canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) This also works for me :D