# tkinter Tab covered by the text widget content when using scrollbar

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

please i have a little problem white my code and i hope you can help me guys,
i'm using a scrollbar to scroll over images in my text widget, but the problem is that the tab window is covered by the images when i scroll. [image][image][image]

> this last picture shows the problem, and i want the tabs to remain showing when i scroll and the images should stay inside the tab.
> here's the code i used:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from tkinter import ttk

def getPaths():
    path = "C://Users/poste/Desktop/trainCascade/p"
    onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]
    return onlyfiles

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        style = ttk.Style()
        style.theme_create('pastel', settings={
            ".": {
                "configure": {
                    "background": 'white',  # All except tabs
                    "font": 'red'
                }
            },
            "TNotebook": {
                "configure": {
                    "background": '#848a98',  # Your margin color
                    "tabmargins": [2, 5, 0, 0],  # margins: left, top, right, separator
                }
            },
            "TNotebook.Tab": {
                "configure": {
                    "background": '#d9ffcc',  # tab color when not selected
                    "padding": [10, 2],
                    "font": "white"
                },
                "map": {
                    "background": [("selected", '#ccffff')],  # Tab color when selected
                    "expand": [("selected", [1, 1, 1, 0])]  # text margins
                }
            }
        })

    style.theme_use('pastel')

    tabControl = ttk.Notebook(self)

    tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
    tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)

    tabControl.add(tab1, text='Tab 1')
    tabControl.add(tab2, text='Tab 2')
    tabControl.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

    text = tk.Text(tab1, wrap="none")
    vsb = tk.Scrollbar(tab1, orient="vertical", command=text.yview)
    text.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
    vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
    text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

    img = []
    resized = []
    final = []
    label = []
    flag = 0
    for i in range(len(getPaths())):
        img.append(Image.open("C://Users/poste/Desktop/trainCascade/p/"+getPaths()[i]))
        resized.append(img[i].resize((107, 80), Image.ANTIALIAS))
        final.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized[i]))

        label.append(tk.Label(image=final[i], bg='white'))
        label[i].image = final[i]
        text.window_create("end", window=label[i])
        flag+=1
        if flag==5:
            text.insert("end", "\n")
            flag=0

    text.configure(state="disabled")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("575x400")
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why not use a [scrollable frame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66215091/11106801) instead of a scrollable text widget. In the frame you can use the `.grid` manager.

Comment: Are images necessary to reproduce this problem, or does the problem also happen if you use text in the label instead of an image? Also, does the problem only occur if you use a custom style, or does it also happen with the built-in styles?

Comment: Indentation is the posted code seems broken. Shouldn't `style.theme_use('pastel')` and the code that follows be indented inside of `__init__`?

Comment: i used the scrollable frame that you suggested and i had the same problem

Comment: @Mouad7991 I noticed that you don't pass in `master` as the first argument when creating those `Label`s. Try using: `tk.Label(text, image=final[i], bg="white")`

Comment: yes this problem happens only when i use images, it doesn't happen when i use text

Comment: @TheLizzard yes it solved the problem, thank you so much

Comment: @Mouad7991 I will write an answer. But basically I think it's a bug in `tcl`.

Comment: @BryanOakley Can you please look at my answer and tell me if my reasoning makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be caused by the lack of `master` argument when creating those labels with the images.

As a minimal working example:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text="If you scroll down the text box, this will " \
                            "be covered.", anchor="w")
label.pack(fill="x")

text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack()

for i in range(50):
    # Adding `text` as the first parameter here solves the problem
    label = tk.Label(text=f"Text label number {i}")
    text.window_create("end", window=label)
    text.insert("end", "\n")

root.mainloop()
```

When you don't specify the `master` argument, `tkinter` uses the first window that you created for the `master`. The problem is that the text widgets tells the `Label` to draw itself giving coordinates that are outside of it's borders. The `Label` check if it's inside it's master's border but as it's master isn't the text widget it is free to draw over your other widgets. I think it's a bug in `tcl`, the library that `tkinter` uses.

Fix:
Always pass in the `master` argument when creating widgets.