# Scrollable buttons in tkinter

Tags: tkinter, button, scrollbar

I have written this code in python tkinter but i want to add
a vertical & a horizontal scrollbar so that i can scroll my buttons vertically & horizontally.
I just want a simple so that as a beginner i can understand it thoroughly. Any help is appreciated.

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.geometry("555x350")

b = Button(root, text="Sample button 1")
b.place(x=0, y=0)

b = Button(root, text="Sample button 1")
b.place(x=0, y=30)

b = Button(root, text="Sample button 1")
b.place(x=0, y=90)


b = Button(root, text="Sample button 1")
b.place(x=0, y=160)


b = Button(root, text="Sample button 1")
b.place(x=0, y=334)

b = Button(root, text="Sample button 1")
b.place(x=120, y=0)


b = Button(root, text="Sample button 1")
b.place(x=230, y=0)


b = Button(root, text="Sample button 1")
b.place(x=472, y=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Put the buttons in a frame like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66215091/11106801) one. Also I suggest using `.pack` or `.grid` instead of `.place`

Comment: I tried doing that but i can't make a frame scrollable.

Comment: Why didn't it work? There are 2 ways of making something scrollable in `tkinter`, and using a `Frame` inside a `Canvas` (like the link I posted), is the easier way (in my opinion).

Comment: Ok I'll look forward to it & later will tell if it works.

Comment: Dear TheLizzard can you give me a simple code because I'm a beginner in tkinter & its hard for me to understand your code.

Comment: The code there comes with 2 examples (run the code and they will automatically start). Just change the `tk.Label`s to `tk.Button`s, if you want buttons instead of labels. Also do you know how for loops work?

Comment: I am not used to go with loops for making buttons in tkinter.

Comment: Please look at some basic python tutorials and make sure you don't fall in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10865116/11106801) trap. Also please note that making multiple widget scrollable (like what you need), isn't part of the basics.

Answer (score 3):

tkinter doesn't support scrolling widgets inside a frame. The only vertically scrollable widgets are the `Text`, `Canvas`, `Listbox`, and `ttk.Treeview` widgets.

Since you are using `place` for the buttons, you can instead add the buttons to a canvas since you can position widgets at exact coordinates. I've shown an example at the end of this pot.

If you prefer to use `grid` or `pack` to arrange, see [Adding a scrollbar to a group of widgets in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3085696/7432) which shows how to put your buttons in a frame, put the frame in a canvas, and then scroll the frame as part of the canvas.

Here's how to do it if you want to place the widgets at specific coordinates by adding them directly to a canvas.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.geometry("555x350")

canvas = Canvas(root)
vsb = Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
hsb = Scrollbar(root, orient="horizontal", command=canvas.xview)

root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=hsb.set, yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
hsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")

b1 = Button(canvas, text="Sample button 1")
b2 = Button(canvas, text="Sample button 1")
b3 = Button(canvas, text="Sample button 1")
b4 = Button(canvas, text="Sample button 1")
b5 = Button(canvas, text="Sample button 1")
b6 = Button(canvas, text="Sample button 1")
b7 = Button(canvas, text="Sample button 1")
b8 = Button(canvas, text="Sample button 1")

canvas.create_window(0, 0, anchor="nw", window=b1)
canvas.create_window(0, 30, anchor="nw", window=b2)
canvas.create_window(0, 90, anchor="nw", window=b3)
canvas.create_window(0, 160, anchor="nw", window=b4)
canvas.create_window(0, 334, anchor="nw", window=b5)
canvas.create_window(120, 0, anchor="nw", window=b6)
canvas.create_window(230, 0, anchor="nw", window=b7)
canvas.create_window(472, 0, anchor="nw", window=b8)

canvas.bind("<Configure>", lambda event: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for help Bryan Oakly but i need a simpler code because as a beginner i can't understand some specific things.