# make scrollbar longer in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

i have made a scrollbar and it works perfect but the size of the scrollbar doesn't match the size of the canvas. i tryed removing the scrollbar.place but it puts the scrollbar in the upper left corner and reallt short. my question is how do i change the length of the scrollbar. thank you very much.

the code:

```
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(self.main_window, width=CANVAS_WIDTH, height=CANVAS_HEIGHT)
canvas.grid()
canvas.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.2, anchor=tkinter.N)
scrollbar = tkinter.Scrollbar(self.main_window, orient=tkinter.VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview)
scrollbar.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=tkinter.N + tkinter.S + tkinter.E)
scrollbar.place(relx=1, rely=0.5, anchor=tkinter.E)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
frame = tkinter.Frame(canvas)
canvas.create_window((0,0), window=frame, anchor=tkinter.NW)
frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda event: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))
```

Comment: You're making the problem harder than it needs to be by using `place`. For scrollbars, `grid` is arguably the best option.

Comment: If you just want a scrollable frame, use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66215091/11106801). It should work on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: @BryanOakley i wrote that even without the place it dosn't work

Answer (score 0):

After making the following changes:

- remove `canvas.place(...)` and `scrollbar.place(...)`
- put `canvas` at the same row (3) of `scrollbar`
- set the width and height of `frame`

Then the height of `scrollbar` will be the same of `canvas`.

```py
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(self.main_window, width=CANVAS_WIDTH, height=CANVAS_HEIGHT)
canvas.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='nsew') # put in same row of scrollbar
#canvas.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.2, anchor=tkinter.N)
scrollbar = tkinter.Scrollbar(self.main_window, orient=tkinter.VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview)
scrollbar.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=tkinter.N + tkinter.S + tkinter.E)
#scrollbar.place(relx=1, rely=0.5, anchor=tkinter.E)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
# give frame a size longer then the canvas to enable scrolling 
frame = tkinter.Frame(canvas, width=CANVAS_WIDTH, height=CANVAS_HEIGHT*2)
canvas.create_window((0,0), window=frame, anchor=tkinter.NW)
frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda event: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))
```