# how can i make tkinter scrollbar when the widgets go off the window

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I have a program that makes a new line containing labels and spinboxes every time a button is clicked, the problem is that if you just keep making new items on the window there comes a point when the next line will not be visible. 
Does anyone have any ideas on how i could make a scroll bar appear when any content goes off the window and becomes invisible?

Comment: Kindly share what you have tried till now

Comment: i have not tried anything i dont know what to try but i am reading a tut about using scroll bars atm and trying to think how i could do this if there is not a commonly used method

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Tkinter scrollbar for frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188420/python-tkinter-scrollbar-for-frame)