# Creating new entry boxes with button Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

How do i make the button to add two box (side by side) below when it is being clicked as the user decided to put more input?

```
def addBox():
    labelframe = Tkinter.Frame()
    labelframe.bind("<Add Input>", callback)
    labelframe.pack()

labelframe = Tkinter.Frame()

labelFrom = Tkinter.Label(labelframe, text= "from")
labelFrom.grid(column=1, row=0)
e = Tkinter.Entry(labelframe)
e.grid(column=1, row=1)

labelTo = Tkinter.Label(labelframe, text= "to")
labelTo.grid(column=2, row=0)
e2 = Tkinter.Entry(labelframe)
e2.grid(column=2, row=1)

labelframe.pack()

addboxButton = Button( root,text='<Add Time Input>', fg="Red",command="addBox")
addboxButton.pack(side=Tkinter.TOP)
```

Comment: Did you indent your function properly?? `def addBox()` should have the codes in indent

Comment: You should not indent the entire code!!! Now all of your code will run when `def addBox()` will be called. Indent in Python works like curly braces `{ }` in javascript, PHP. So basically indent only that part of the code which you want it to be inside the function.

Comment: You **shouldn't** use **`pack()`** and **`grid()`** together.

Comment: Use function name without quotation marks `command=addBox`

Answer (score 4):

This is example how to add `Entry`.

Probably you get problem because you use quotation marks in `command=addBox`

Because you will have to get values from entries you have to remeber them on list.
I add button which print text from entries.

```
from Tkinter import *

#------------------------------------

def addBox():
    print "ADD"

    ent = Entry(root)
    ent.pack()

    all_entries.append( ent )

#------------------------------------

def showEntries():

    for number, ent in enumerate(all_entries):
        print number, ent.get()

#------------------------------------

all_entries = []

root = Tk()

showButton = Button(root, text='Show all text', command=showEntries)
showButton.pack()

addboxButton = Button(root, text='<Add Time Input>', fg="Red", command=addBox)
addboxButton.pack()

root.mainloop()

#------------------------------------
```

---

**EDIT:**

Example with boxes side by side.

I use new frame to keep entries side by side using `grid()`.
This way I don't mix `grid()` with `pack()` in main window/frame.

I use `len(all_entries)` to get number of next free column.

```
from Tkinter import *

#------------------------------------

def addBox():
    print "ADD"

    # I use len(all_entries) to get nuber of next free column
    next_column = len(all_entries)

    # add label in first row 
    lab = Label(frame_for_boxes, text=str(next_column+1))
    lab.grid(row=0, column=next_column)

    # add entry in second row
    ent = Entry(frame_for_boxes)
    ent.grid(row=1, column=next_column)

    all_entries.append( ent )

#------------------------------------

def showEntries():

    for number, ent in enumerate(all_entries):
        print number, ent.get()

#------------------------------------

all_entries = []

root = Tk()

showButton = Button(root, text='Show all text', command=showEntries)
showButton.pack()

addboxButton = Button(root, text='<Add Time Input>', fg="Red", command=addBox)
addboxButton.pack()

frame_for_boxes = Frame(root)
frame_for_boxes.pack()

root.mainloop()

#------------------------------------
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

Another example:

```
from Tkinter import *

#------------------------------------

def addBox():
    print "ADD"

    frame = Frame(root)
    frame.pack()

    Label(frame, text='From').grid(row=0, column=0)

    ent1 = Entry(frame)
    ent1.grid(row=1, column=0)

    Label(frame, text='To').grid(row=0, column=1)

    ent2 = Entry(frame)
    ent2.grid(row=1, column=1)

    all_entries.append( (ent1, ent2) )

#------------------------------------

def showEntries():

    for number, (ent1, ent2) in enumerate(all_entries):
        print number, ent1.get(), ent2.get()

#------------------------------------

all_entries = []

root = Tk()

showButton = Button(root, text='Show all text', command=showEntries)
showButton.pack()

addboxButton = Button(root, text='<Add Time Input>', fg="Red", command=addBox)
addboxButton.pack()

root.mainloop()

#------------------------------------
```

[image]

Comment: what if i need two box side by side( when button is clicked,it will create two boxes together side by side? i can't seem to make that works

Comment: If you need boxes side by side then use `grid(column=...)`. But don't mix `pack()` and `grid()` in one `Frame`. If you use `pack()` in one frame then create second frame, put it inside first frame and then you can use `grid()` inside second frame. See new example.

Comment: thank you, i can't seem to get the scrollbar working by the way the user needs more inputs it needs to be able to scroll.

Comment: As I know the only method is to use canvas with frame inside to  scroll it. See more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188420/python-tkinter-scrollbar-for-frame

Comment: yes i did read on that earlier today,but i can't seem to get it right

Comment: This is the only way - but difficult way.

Comment: Search on internet maybe someone create tkinter widget `Scrolled Frame`

Comment: anyway this can be updated with the latest python version?

Comment: @excelguy you have to use `from tkiner` instead of `from Tkinter` (see `t` instead of `T`)  and `print()` instead of `print` (you need brackets)- and it works with Python 3.

Comment: @excelguy - yes `tkinter` - I made a typo.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the indentation is a whole mess, so I don't know where does the addBox function end ..

Second, I don't think you need a button, I suppose a checkbutton will do the same thing and it's also more common and familiar to users, I once had this problem and I simply created an entry box and put above it a label indicating that it's optional, and as for code, I simply ignored it if it was empty and verified the input if I found any input ..
Howerver, that was for only one entry box, and you probably will need something more complex ..

#### See this ..

```
class OptionsView(Frame):
    """Frame for options in main window"""
    def __init__(self, x, y, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.placed = False
        self.hidden = False
        self.btn = Button(self, text = 'Button attached to the frame ..', command = lambda: print('Button in frame clicked ..')).pack()
    def pack(self):
        self.place(x = self.x, y = self.y)
        self.placed = True
    def toggle_view(self):
        if self.hidden:
            self.pack()
            self.hidden = False
        else:
            self.place_forget()
            self.hidden = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    def m_frame():
        if val.get() and not options_frame.placed:
            print('Showing Frame ..')
            options_frame.pack()
        else:
            print('Toggling Frame ..')
            options_frame.toggle_view()

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('300x400+500+600')
    root.title('Testing Hiding Frames ..')
    options_frame = OptionsView(200, 300, root)

    val = BooleanVar(value = False)
    Checkbutton(text = 'View more Options ..', var = val, command = m_frame).place(x=root.winfo_height()/2, y=root.winfo_width()/2)

    try: root.mainloop()
    except e: showerror('Error!', 'It seems there\'s a problem ..', str(e))
```

Ofcourse you can also modify the length and the x axis of the main window if you want to be more realistic ..