# Tkinter button not working geometry error

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I'm learning tkinter and trying to make a button but when I run my code an error comes up saying

> .TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack

This is my code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import Button
window=tkinter.Tk()
#title
window.title("Elvoria")
#text
label=tkinter.Label(window, text = "Welcome To Elovria").pack()
#button
bt = Button(window,text="Start")
bt.grid(column=1,row=1)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You cannot use both `.grid` and `.pack` in the same container (window,frame...). And also your import statement is wrong

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54315989/cant-understand-pack-and-grid-geometry-with-tkinter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot use geometry manager pack inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23584325/cannot-use-geometry-manager-pack-inside)

Comment: @PCM I agree for the first part but what do you mean by the *import statement is wrong*?

Comment: @TheLizzard `import tkinter` was not there when I commented ;)

Comment: @PCM That makes sense. My bad. I should have checked the edits :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use only `grid` or `pack` so change the label placement to `grid`

Comment: What you say is incorrect. You can use `.place` along with grid and pack. But you cannot use `.pack` and `.grid` together

Comment: thank you i used .grid instead of pack and it worked