# Adding a scrollbar to window

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I currency have this, but I would like to add a scrollbar. All the methods I've seen have either `Listbox` or `canvas` which I'm not using.

```
import Tkinter as tk

file = open('curfile')
data = file.read()
file.close()
window = tk.Tk()

Results = tk.Label(window, text=data, justify='left')
Results.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
Results.configure(background='black', foreground='white')

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: The Problem is that Frame, Tk and Toplevel do not support scrollbars. That is why you need a Listbox or a Canvas. Possible Duplicate: [Python Tkinter scrollbar for frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188420/python-tkinter-scrollbar-for-frame)

Comment: How would I go about doing what my code currently does via `Listbox` or `Canvas`?

Comment: Use [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16198198/1320237) and change it.

Comment: Text widgets also take scrollbars.