# Tkinter - Scrollable list with images and editable text

Tags: python, image, text, tkinter, scrollable

Using Tkinter I want to create a scrollable list(rows and columns) with images and editable text. The first column should contain images and the second column should contain tags(text) for the respective images in the previous column.

Hence a row should contain an image in a column and text in the next column.

Please let me know, what widget i need to use in Tkinter in order to achieve this.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a single frame for the images and editable text. You can use a text widget for the editable text, and align them using grid.

Then, place the frame in a canvas so that it can be scrolled. There are many questions and answers on this site related to scrolling a frame. See, for example, this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16198198/7432