# resizeable scrollable canvas with tkinter

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, resize, scrollable

Here my code for a very simple gui:

```
from Tkinter import *

class my_gui(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        # main tk object
        self.root = Tk()

        # init Frame
        Frame.__init__(self, self.root)

        # create frame (gray window)
        self.frame=Frame(self.root,width=100,height=100)
        self.frame.grid(row=0,column=0)

        self.__add_scroll_bars()

        self.__create_canvas()

        self.__add_plot()

    def __create_canvas(self):
        # create white area in the window for plotting
        # width and height are only the visible size of the white area, scrollregion is the area the user can see by scrolling
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.frame,bg='#FFFFFF',width=300,height=300,scrollregion=(0,0,500,500))

        # with this command the window is filled with the canvas
        self.canvas.pack(side=LEFT,expand=True,fill=BOTH)

        # position and size of the canvas is used for configuration of the scroll bars
        self.canvas.config(xscrollcommand=self.hbar.set, yscrollcommand=self.vbar.set)

        # add command to the scroll bars to scroll the canvas
        self.hbar.config(command = self.canvas.xview)
        self.vbar.config(command = self.canvas.yview)

    def __add_scroll_bars(self):
        # add scroll bars
        self.hbar=Scrollbar(self.frame,orient=HORIZONTAL)
        self.hbar.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)
        self.vbar=Scrollbar(self.frame,orient=VERTICAL)
        self.vbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)

    def __add_plot(self):
        # create a rectangle
        self.canvas.create_polygon(10, 10, 10, 150, 200, 150, 200, 10,  fill="gray", outline="black")

    def mainLoop(self):
        # This function starts an endlos running thread through the gui
        self.root.mainloop()

    def __quit(self):
        # close everything
        self.root.quit()

    def mainLoop(self):
        # This function starts an endlos running thread through the gui
        self.root.mainloop()

# init gui
my_gui = my_gui()
# execute gui
my_gui.mainLoop()
```

I have two questions:

1) I want if I resize the gui, that then the scrollbars are always on the Ends of the gui and I resize the canvas.

2) If I resize the GUI and the canvas, then the rectangle in the canvas shall be resized (for example if the new size of gui and canvas is four times the old size, then the new size of rectangle is twize the old size).

I search a solution for the first problem and for the second problem seperately.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works very well, to get what I want with the minimal scrollable canvas size. But there is still the bug, when the gui was made larger and when it seems so, that one can not scroll, there is the possibility to click on the left or upper arrow of the scroll bars and so to scroll the canvas, what sould not be possible.

```
from Tkinter import *


class ScrollableFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, minimal_canvas_size, *args, **kw):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''

        Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kw)

        self.minimal_canvas_size = minimal_canvas_size

        # create a vertical scrollbar
        vscrollbar = Scrollbar(self, orient = VERTICAL)
        vscrollbar.pack(fill = Y, side = RIGHT, expand = FALSE)

        # create a horizontal scrollbar
        hscrollbar = Scrollbar(self, orient = HORIZONTAL)
        hscrollbar.pack(fill = X, side = BOTTOM, expand = FALSE)

        #Create a canvas object and associate the scrollbars with it
        self.canvas = Canvas(self, bd = 0, highlightthickness = 0, yscrollcommand = vscrollbar.set, xscrollcommand = hscrollbar.set)
        self.canvas.pack(side = LEFT, fill = BOTH, expand = TRUE)

        #Associate scrollbars with canvas view
        vscrollbar.config(command = self.canvas.yview)
        hscrollbar.config(command = self.canvas.xview)


        # set the view to 0,0 at initialization

        self.canvas.xview_moveto(0)
        self.canvas.yview_moveto(0)

        self.canvas.config(scrollregion='0 0 %s %s' % self.minimal_canvas_size)

        # create an interior frame to be created inside the canvas

        self.interior = interior = Frame(self.canvas)
        interior_id = self.canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=interior,
                anchor=NW)

        # track changes to the canvas and frame width and sync them,
        # also updating the scrollbar

        def _configure_interior(event):
            # update the scrollbars to match the size of the inner frame
            size = (max(interior.winfo_reqwidth(), self.minimal_canvas_size[0]), max(interior.winfo_reqheight(), self.minimal_canvas_size[1]))
            self.canvas.config(scrollregion='0 0 %s %s' % size)
            if interior.winfo_reqwidth() != self.canvas.winfo_width():
                # update the canvas's width to fit the inner frame
                self.canvas.config(width = interior.winfo_reqwidth())
        interior.bind('<Configure>', _configure_interior)


class my_gui(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        # main tk object
        self.root = Tk()

        # init Frame
        Frame.__init__(self, self.root)

        minimal_canvas_size = (500, 500)

        # create frame (gray window)

        self.frame = ScrollableFrame(self.root, minimal_canvas_size)
        self.frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

        self.__add_plot()

    def __add_plot(self):
        # create a rectangle
        self.frame.canvas.create_polygon(10, 10, 10, 150, 200, 150, 200, 10,  fill="gray", outline="black")

    def mainLoop(self):
        # This function starts an endlos running thread through the gui
        self.root.mainloop()

    def __quit(self):
        # close everything
        self.root.quit()


# init gui
my_gui = my_gui()
# execute gui
my_gui.mainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following way to integrate my frame into your gui class:

```
from Tkinter import *


class ScrollableFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kw):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''

        Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kw)

        # create a vertical scrollbar
        vscrollbar = Scrollbar(self, orient = VERTICAL)
        vscrollbar.pack(fill = Y, side = RIGHT, expand = FALSE)

        # create a horizontal scrollbar
        hscrollbar = Scrollbar(self, orient = HORIZONTAL)
        hscrollbar.pack(fill = X, side = BOTTOM, expand = FALSE)

        #Create a canvas object and associate the scrollbars with it
        self.canvas = Canvas(self, bd = 0, highlightthickness = 0, yscrollcommand = vscrollbar.set, xscrollcommand = hscrollbar.set)
        self.canvas.pack(side = LEFT, fill = BOTH, expand = TRUE)

        #Associate scrollbars with canvas view
        vscrollbar.config(command = self.canvas.yview)
        hscrollbar.config(command = self.canvas.xview)


        # set the view to 0,0 at initialization

        self.canvas.xview_moveto(0)
        self.canvas.yview_moveto(0)

        # create an interior frame to be created inside the canvas

        self.interior = interior = Frame(self.canvas)
        interior_id = self.canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=interior,
                anchor=NW)

        # track changes to the canvas and frame width and sync them,
        # also updating the scrollbar

        def _configure_interior(event):
            # update the scrollbars to match the size of the inner frame
            size = (interior.winfo_reqwidth(), interior.winfo_reqheight())
            self.canvas.config(scrollregion='0 0 %s %s' % size)
            if interior.winfo_reqwidth() != self.canvas.winfo_width():
                # update the canvas's width to fit the inner frame
                self.canvas.config(width = interior.winfo_reqwidth())
        interior.bind('<Configure>', _configure_interior)


class my_gui(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        # main tk object
        self.root = Tk()

        # init Frame
        Frame.__init__(self, self.root)

        # create frame (gray window)

        self.frame = ScrollableFrame(self.root)
        self.frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)


        #self.__add_scroll_bars()

        #self.__create_canvas()

        self.__add_plot()

    def __add_plot(self):
        # create a rectangle
        self.frame.canvas.create_polygon(10, 10, 10, 150, 200, 150, 200, 10,  fill="gray", outline="black")

    def mainLoop(self):
        # This function starts an endlos running thread through the gui
        self.root.mainloop()

    def __quit(self):
        # close everything
        self.root.quit()


# init gui
my_gui = my_gui()
# execute gui
my_gui.mainLoop()
```

This should essentially solve your first problem. As for the second problem you'll need to create a function to re-render the canvas every time you resize it. In a way similar to the _configure_interior function.

Comment: Hallo,  for the first it works,  but in this example the scrollbars makes no sense, there is nothing to scroll, the canvas has always exact the same size as the scrollbars, I can never scroll. I wanted to scroll when the GUI is small enough (maybe when the gui is smaller than 500 times 500, then I want to scroll this size..  For the second when you make the gui larger, the scroll bar seems so, that you can not scroll. But when you click on the left arrow of the bottom scroll bar, then you can see, that the rectangle moves to the right. Is this a bug?

Comment: In some cases it works to replace the line "size = (interior.winfo_reqwidth(), interior.winfo_reqheight())" by "size = ( max( 500, interior.winfo_reqwidth() ), max( 500, interior.winfo_reqheight() ) )
"
to get in the most cases a scrollable canvas of size 500 times 500 at minimum. But the _configure_interior function seems not to be called in each case, when the size of the gui was changed.

Comment: I did not encounter the bug when I executed it. As for the scrollbars not making sense, that is because you just have a plain canvas with a polygon in it. You could `pack` in other elements (like labels, checkboxes, buttons etc) to see that the scrollbars would be activated once the window size is lesser than the required size to display all elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this following example, or integrate it in your class.
You could create a frame like this by calling.

```
self.frame = ScrollableFrame(self.root)
self.frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
```

---

Create a class like this for your frame:

```
from Tkinter import *    
class ScrollableFrame(Frame):
'''
Creates a scrollable frame
'''

  def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kw):
    '''
    Constructor
    '''

    Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kw)

    # create a vertical scrollbar
    vscrollbar = Scrollbar(self, orient = VERTICAL)
    vscrollbar.pack(fill = Y, side = RIGHT, expand = FALSE)

    # create a horizontal scrollbar
    hscrollbar = Scrollbar(self, orient = HORIZONTAL)
    hscrollbar.pack(fill = X, side = BOTTOM, expand = FALSE)

    #Create a canvas object and associate the scrollbars with it
    canvas = Canvas(self, bd = 0, highlightthickness = 0, yscrollcommand = vscrollbar.set, xscrollcommand = hscrollbar.set)
    canvas.pack(side = LEFT, fill = BOTH, expand = TRUE)

    #Associate scrollbars with canvas view
    vscrollbar.config(command = canvas.yview)
    hscrollbar.config(command = canvas.xview)


    # set the view to 0,0 at initialization

    canvas.xview_moveto(0)
    canvas.yview_moveto(0)

    # create an interior frame to be created inside the canvas

    self.interior = interior = Frame(canvas)
    interior_id = canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=interior,
            anchor=NW)

    # track changes to the canvas and frame width and sync them,
    # also updating the scrollbar

    def _configure_interior(event):
        # update the scrollbars to match the size of the inner frame
        size = (interior.winfo_reqwidth(), interior.winfo_reqheight())
        canvas.config(scrollregion='0 0 %s %s' % size)
        if interior.winfo_reqwidth() != canvas.winfo_width():
            # update the canvas's width to fit the inner frame
            canvas.config(width = interior.winfo_reqwidth())
    interior.bind('<Configure>', _configure_interior)
```

You could use this to obtain the result you want. Horizontal and Vertical scrolling are both enabled for this frame and scrollbar positions can be set using 'side' field.
For the second part of your question, could you elucidate further.

Reference: Gonzo's answer
[Python Tkinter scrollbar for frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188420/python-tkinter-scrollbar-for-frame)

Comment: Do you have a simple example, where this class ScrollableFrame is used with a canvas inside for example?  I don't really understand how I can integrate this class in my example.  I see, that a lot of code is the same like the Scrollbars and I see, that the trick for resizeable Scrollbars seems to be the _configure_interior function and the create_window function, but I don't really understand why.

Comment: This example makes a canvas with horizontal and vertical scrollbars, but from what I can tell no slider ever appears, even when the size of the frame exceeds the size of the canvas it is placed on.

https://pastebin.com/J7d0ChzX