# How can i add a scrollbar for the entire window in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have research but all i found is using listbox or another widgets and a i need it in the window and i have seen examples that are supposed to be for the window but when i tried it says that there are some commands that doesn't exists

Comment: Only some widgets are scrollable, and the root window is not one of them. A Canvas is scrollable, and a Canvas allows other widgets to be placed inside it so most people use a Canvas when they need a scrollable window. Many people have abstracted this [for instance this](https://gist.github.com/novel-yet-trivial/3eddfce704db3082e38c84664fc1fdf8).

Comment: you might want to refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188420/python-tkinter-scrollbar-for-frame