# Main method to call a custom object in Python

Tags: python, object, tkinter

I was trying to fix something related to what an object returns when you use an object as an argument.

For example, I have a custom object and I want to use it as a parent for another tkinter widget, so I need to return a tkinter object to place the new tkinter object into my custom object, but my custom object returns that is an object of a custom class.

I can explain this much better on code:

```
class CustomFrame(object):
    def __init__(self,**args):
        #code that works

        #The next is an external object that have a variable that I need to call externally.
        #The variable is "interior"
        self.externalobject = anotherobject('random')

cfr1 = CustomFrame()

label1 = Label(cfr1)
```

Now I want to use the "self.externalobject.interior" as the parent for label1
But I want to make it friendly just calling "cfr1" instead of "self.externalobject.interior"

I know that if I use the **call** method and I return the value that I need it will work if I pass "cfr1" as a function, but I want to make it the more Pythonic as possible.

So I need to know if there's another special method or something to modify what it returns.

EDIT:
So, this is part of the code I am using:

This is the code of the vertical scrolled frame (not my code).

```
class VerticalScrolledFrame(Frame):
    """A pure Tkinter scrollable frame that actually works!
    * Use the 'interior' attribute to place widgets inside the scrollable frame
    * Construct and pack/place/grid normally
    * This frame only allows vertical scrolling

    """
    def __init__(self, parent, bg, *args, **kw):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kw)            

        # create a canvas object and a vertical scrollbar for scrolling it
        vscrollbar = Scrollbar(self, orient=VERTICAL)
        canvas = Canvas(self, bd=0, highlightthickness=0,
                        yscrollcommand=vscrollbar.set,bg=bg)
        vscrollbar.config(command=canvas.yview)
        canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=TRUE)

        # reset the view
        canvas.xview_moveto(0)
        canvas.yview_moveto(0)

        # create a frame inside the canvas which will be scrolled with it
        self.interior = interior = Frame(canvas,bg=bg)
        interior_id = canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=interior,
                                           anchor=NW)

        a = Frame(self.interior,height=10,bg=dynamicBackground())
        a.pack()

        def canvasscroll(event):
            canvas.yview('scroll',int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units")

        def _configure_canvas(event):
            a.configure(height=10)
            a.update()
            mylist = interior.winfo_children()
            for i in mylist:
                lasty=i.winfo_height()+i.winfo_y()
            a.configure(height=lasty)
            if interior.winfo_reqwidth() != canvas.winfo_width():
                # update the inner frame's width to fill the canvas
                canvas.itemconfigure(interior_id, width=canvas.winfo_width())
            if canvas.winfo_height()<lasty:
                vscrollbar.pack(fill=Y, side=RIGHT, expand=FALSE)
                canvas.config(scrollregion=(0,0,0,lasty))
                canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", canvasscroll)
            else:
                canvas.unbind_all("<MouseWheel>")
                try:
                    vscrollbar.pack_forget()
                except:
                    pass
                canvas.config(scrollregion=(0,0,0,0))


        canvas.bind('<Configure>', _configure_canvas)
```

And this is the code for my custom object:

```
class UtilityPanel(object):
    def __init__(self,parent='*',title='Main Title',state='normal',bg='red'):
        super().__init__()
        if parent != '*':
            self.parent=parent
        else:
            raise TypeError('You must specify a parent for this widget.')
        self.title=title

        global subpanels

        if len(subpanels) == 0:
            self.panelid = 'sp-1'
            subpanels.append('sp-1')
        else:
            self.panelid = 'sp-'+str(int(subpanels[-1].split('-')[1])+1)
            subpanels.append(self.panelid)

        self.panel = VerticalScrolledFrame(self.parent,bg=bg,width=600,height=200,name=self.panelid)

    def __call__(self,name):
        return(self.panel.interior)

    def pack(self):
        self.panel.place(x=300)
        global activepanel
        activepanel = self.panelid
```

So, if i pass the argument like `label1 = Label(cfr1.panel.interior)` it works, but I want it to make it work just passing cfr1 as an argument.

Comment: I think there's a good question in here, but it's hard to read, partly because you've put some of it as comments in the code. (I didn't downvote BTW).

Comment: I made changes to make it better to read, just want to explain every part of the "uncompleted" code that I post

Comment: The only thing that can be the parent of a Tkinter widget is another Tkinter widget.  For your custom object to fulfill that role, it needs to derive from a Tkinter class - I suppose `Frame` in your case.

Comment: Yes, this is it, I need a Frame, self.externalobject.interior is a Frame, but I need to return it just calling cfr1.

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to return it"... I am not sure I understand your need here. That said I did notice you are missing `super().__init__()` under your `__init__` method and you need to inherit from frame.

Comment: What about doing this: `label1 = Label(cfr1.externalobject)`? Is this what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, with `label1 = Label(cfr1.externalobject.interior)` works.

Comment: But it's what I want to avoid.

Comment: Ahhhh ok. Can you tell me what `interior` is exactly. Is it another container or just some variable holding a value?

Comment: I have edited the main question to show how it works.

Comment: I see you are using the code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188420/python-tkinter-scrollbar-for-frame). I am not sure if there is a way to link to the `interior` frame without doing `cfr1.externalobject.interior`. If there is all the testing I have done has failed and I am just unaware of the correct method to do this. Good luck. I hope someone knows the solution if there is one. I am curious myself to see if there is a way to do this.

Comment: If you want to use this custom object as a parent to another widget, why aren't you inheriting from a widget such as Frame? That makes this problem trivial. Anything else will result in confusing code that others will find hard to understand.

Comment: Just because I want to use a property of a custom object created by a custom object. Not a single custom object instead.
So, the same way, with `__repr__`, that it's the representation of the object when you show it, and it's editable, I need a method similar, but for when you call the object, so, instead of calling the object and return the type of the object, return whatever I want.

Answer (score 3):

I think I understand the issue the OP is having here. They are unable to use the frame as the container for their label and that is because they are missing `super()` and need to inherit from Frame.

Change this:

```
class CustomFrame(object):
    def __init__(self,**args):
```

To this:

```
class CustomFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self,**args):
        super().__init__()
```

And you should be able to use the customer frame as the container for your label.

Based on your comments below try this:

```
class CustomFrame(anotherobject):
    def __init__(self,**args):
        super().__init__()
```

This should inherit all methods and attributes of that object.

Comment: Ok, I think I haven't explained correctly, but this is close to what I want.
I explain  a little more, I have an external custom object that is a scrollable frame for tkinter, and I have created a new object to give it new properties and  act as a new object.
This custom scrollable frame have the attribute interior, which is what I need to pass to a widget as a parent to fit in it.
But I need to do make it like any widget in tkinter

Comment: So, I need to, return this interior attribute of the scrollable frame, that is inside my new custom object, just passing the name of the custom object...
Sorry, if I still don't explaining well, but it's difficult to me due to the language.

Comment: Then instead of inheriting from `Frame` you can inherit from your customer object. That should work here.

Comment: It is a little unclear what you want. It almost sounds like you want to be able to use `CustomFrame()` as a way to pass another object as the container. So say `CustomFrame` inherits from `OtherObject` and you want to do `Label(CustomeFrame)` resulting in basically `Label(OtherObject)`. Is that correct?

Comment: I know what you're saying, but doesn't work because I define the scrollable frame into the custom object, so I can't inherit the property from an object that is created inside.

Comment: Ok, wait a moment, I will edit the main post with the code, I think this could give a clearer idea of what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to implicitly cast/coerce one type of object to another.

If you want to be "pythonic", recall,

```
>>> import this
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
...
```

Implicitly doing things can cause trouble.

I see nothing wrong with using the `call` magic function to get the attribute you want, or start looking at properties and decorators.

There's a full list of magic methods [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names)

Answer (score 0):

You *could* probably achieve what you want if you created your own custom subclass of `tk.Label` that basically does the unpacking for you.

*(Disclaimer: I have never used tkinter, so I cannot tell if this actually works in the context of that framework. This example is merely to demonstrate the concept I am trying to outline here.)*

```
class CustomLabel(tk.Label):

    def __init__(self, master, **options):
        if isinstance(master, CustomFrame):
            master = master.externalobject.interior
        super().__init__(master=master, **options)
```

With that you should be able to use `CustomLabel(cfr1)`.

However, I strongly support the message that @doctorlove conveys in their answer. IMHO, the most pythonic way would indeed be `Label(cfr1.externalobject.interior)`, your suggested approach using `__call__` or a property inside `CustomFrame` that provides a shortcut to `externalobject.interior`:

```
@property
def interior(self):
    return self.externalobject.interior
```

which you would use like so `Label(crf1.interior)`