# How do we add a scroll bar when the entry boxes are more than the window height in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, jupyter

First, when the number of rectangles is entered less than 24 it works fine. When I put the number of rectangles more than 24, the entry boxes exceed the window height and I cannot see it. I want to use a scroll bar at the right side when the number of entry boxes exceeds the window height. The documentation implies that only the List, Textbox, Canvas and Entry widgets support the scrollbar interface. So, how can I do for gridboxes?

Note : The code is verifiable.

```
from tkinter import *

temp_recta = []

def save_content(top):
    for j in range(0, int(rectangles.get()) * 2):
        temp_recta.append(rectangle_values[j].get())

    root = Toplevel()

    l1 = Label(root, text="Size of Sheet[Height]:")
    l1.grid(row=0, column=0)

    l2 = Label(root, text="Size of Sheet[Width]:")
    l2.grid(row=1, column=0)

    height = StringVar()
    e1 = Entry(root, textvariable=height)
    e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

    width = StringVar()
    e2 = Entry(root, textvariable=width)
    e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

    b5 = Button(root, text="Proceed", width=12, command=lambda: save_sheetsize(e1, e2, root))
    b5.grid(row=2, column=0)
    b6 = Button(root, text="Back", width=12, command=lambda: (root.destroy(), top.deiconify()))
    b6.grid(row=2, column=1)

    root.title("Sheet Size")

def save_sheetsize(e1, e2, root):
    global x
    global y
    x = float(e2.get())
    y = float(e1.get())
    root.destroy()
    window.destroy()

rectangle_values = []
x = 0
y = 0
k = 0

def open_window():
    window.withdraw()
    global k
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("Rectangles")

    for i in range(0, int(rectangles.get()) * 2):
        if (i % 2) == 0:
            l4 = Label(top, text="Size of rectangle:")
            l4.grid(row=i, column=0)

        rectangle_values.append(StringVar())
        en = Entry(top, textvariable=rectangle_values[i])
        en.grid(row=i, column=1)


    b3 = Button(top, text="Save", width=12, command=lambda: (top.withdraw(), save_content(top)))
    b3.grid(row=int(rectangles.get()) * 2 + 1, column=0)
    b4 = Button(top, text="Back", width=12, command=lambda: (top.destroy(), window.deiconify()))
    b4.grid(row=int(rectangles.get()) * 2 + 1, column=1)
    k = int(rectangles.get())

window = Tk()

l3 = Label(window, text="Number of Rectangles:")
l3.grid(row=0, column=0)

rectangles = StringVar()
e3 = Entry(window, textvariable=rectangles)
e3.grid(row=0, column=1)

b1 = Button(window, text='Submit', width=12, command=open_window)
b1.grid(row=3, column=1)

window.title("Rectangle Configuration")
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: There is a widget called Scrollbar, just follow any online tutorial/manual on it, ex. http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/scrollbar.htm

Comment: Sorry, but, I coundn't get it to work on my window.

Comment: Then please share the code what you tried, what error/problem you faced.

Comment: scrollbar.config, on this line I don t know what to write as a command.

Comment: Check this post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085696/adding-a-scrollbar-to-a-group-of-widgets-in-tkinter

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple class to do this. Add your text widget and it will give you a scrollbar when your window is full of text.

```
import tkinter
class Scrollbar:
    def __init__(self,text):
        self.frame = text.master
        self.text = text
        self.text.configure(wrap='none')
        self.for_x_view()
        self.for_y_view()

    def for_x_view(self):
        # scroll Bar x For width
        scroll_x=tkinter.Scrollbar(self.frame, orient='horizontal',command=self.text.xview)
        scroll_x.config(command=self.text.xview)
        self.text.configure(xscrollcommand=scroll_x.set)
        scroll_x.pack(side='bottom', fill='x', anchor='w')
        return

    def for_y_view(self):
        # Scroll Bar y For Height
        scroll_y = tkinter.Scrollbar(self.frame)
        scroll_y.config(command=self.text.yview)
        self.text.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set)
        scroll_y.pack(side='right', fill='y')       
        return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    pad = tkinter.Text(root,wrap='none')
    Scrollbar(pad)
    pad.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: In my case, it is the gridboxes. so, I am confused. And all the examples are about list.

Comment: So just replace scroll_x.pack() with scroll_x .grid() and it will work fine. Do it with the y also.

Comment: I didn t get it mate

Comment: You can put them in a frame and then apply the scrollbar to the frame.

Comment: You can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188420/python-tkinter-scrollbar-for-frame

Comment: This doesn't work for the question being asked. This solution only works for a widget that natively supports scrollbars. The OP is asking about scrolling a group of widgets.