# How to make the second canvas window scrollable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I want the second window which appears after clicking next to be scrollable. It is not working. I tried the same way for the first window but for the second window, it doesn't seem to be working.

```
import tkinter as tk

def option_window():
    def toplevel():
        top = tk.Toplevel()
        top.wm_geometry("794x370")
        top.title('Optimized Map')

        optimized_canvas = tk.Canvas(top)
        optimized_canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        optimized_canvas_scroll = tk.Scrollbar(optimized_canvas, command=optimized_canvas.yview)
        optimized_canvas_scroll.place(relx=1, rely=0, relheight=1, anchor=tk.NE)
        optimized_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=optimized_canvas_scroll.set, scrollregion=())
        optimized_canvas.bind_all('<MouseWheel>', lambda event: optimized_canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units"))

        l0 = tk.Label(optimized_canvas, text="Sheet")
        l0.pack()

        l1 = tk.Label(optimized_canvas, text="Sheet")
        l1.pack()

    toplevel()

window = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, bg="white", width=1100, height=580, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
submit_button = tk.Button(canvas, text="Next >>>",font= "calibri 13", command = option_window)
canvas.create_window(50, 50, window=submit_button, anchor=tk.NW)




window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tkinter scrollbar for frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188420/tkinter-scrollbar-for-frame)

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Does the program crash? Does the scrollbar not appear? Does it appear, but it scrolls the wrong window? Does it scroll in the wrong direction? ...?

Comment: @BryanOakley The second window doesn't scroll.

Comment: There's not enough information in the second window to scroll. Plus, you're explicitly setting the `scrollregion` to an empty value.