# All labels disappear if i add a scrollbar

Tags: python, tkinter

In my program I want to add a lot of labels, and to see them all they require a scrollbar. If i add a scrollbar to my code then all labels disappear. I apologize for the long codes, I just couldn't get it work without all the extra code for some reason.

Code without the scrollbar:

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial


words = ["test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test"]
def validateLogin(password):
    print(password.get())
    if password.get() == "test":
        newWindow = Tk()
        newWindow.geometry('1800x800')
        newWindow.title("Passwords")
        tkWindow.destroy()
        for index, word in enumerate(words):
            Label(newWindow, text=word).grid(row=index, column=0)

    if password.get() != "test":
        Label(tkWindow, text="Wrong password!", fg='red').grid(row=5, column=2)

#window
tkWindow = Tk()
tkWindow.geometry('250x100')
tkWindow.title('Passwords')

#password label and password entry box
passwordLabel = Label(tkWindow,text="Password").grid(row=1, column=0)
password = StringVar()
passwordEntry = Entry(tkWindow, textvariable=password, show='*').grid(row=1, column=2)

validateLogin = partial(validateLogin, password)

#login button
loginButton = Button(tkWindow, text="Login", command=validateLogin).grid(row=4, column=2)

tkWindow.mainloop()
```

Code with the scrollbar:

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial


words = ["test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test"]
def validateLogin(password):
    print(password.get())
    if password.get() == "test":
        newWindow = Tk()
        newWindow.geometry('1800x800')
        newWindow.title("Passwords")
        scrollbar = Scrollbar(newWindow)
        scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        tkWindow.destroy()
        for index, word in enumerate(words):
            Label(newWindow, text=word).grid(row=index, column=0)

    if password.get() != "test":
        Label(tkWindow, text="Wrong password!", fg='red').grid(row=5, column=2)

#window
tkWindow = Tk()
tkWindow.geometry('250x100')
tkWindow.title('Passwords')

#password label and password entry box
passwordLabel = Label(tkWindow,text="Password").grid(row=1, column=0)
password = StringVar()
passwordEntry = Entry(tkWindow, textvariable=password, show='*').grid(row=1, column=2)

validateLogin = partial(validateLogin, password)

#login button
loginButton = Button(tkWindow, text="Login", command=validateLogin).grid(row=4, column=2)

tkWindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: The labels "disappear" because your program is encountering errors (see the console when you run it), stemming from the fact that you use `grid` for labels and `pack` for the scrollbar - you have to use the same method for placing everything in a frame

Comment: On top of this, your scrollbar is not doing anything at the moment; it is slightly more complicated to link the scrollbar to the Frame you want to scroll through (more than just placing it in the frame).  But you can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16188420/13386979) (and likely others) for a working example

Comment: @Tom - regarding: you have to use the same method for placing everything in a frame ~ this is only half true. You just can't use `grid` and `pack` together. You can use `place` all you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems that I have seen here, the first problem is that you're trying to use `.grid` for the label displaying the text, and using `.pack` for the scrollbar.  You can't use both `.grid` and `.pack` in the same window.

Here's the code where I corrected this problem by replacing `.grid(row=index, column=0)` with `.pack(anchor = W)`

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial


words = ["test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test"]
def validateLogin(password):
    print(password.get())
    if password.get() == "test":
        newWindow = Tk()
        newWindow.geometry('1800x800')
        newWindow.title("Passwords")
        scrollbar = Scrollbar(newWindow)
        scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        tkWindow.destroy()
        for index, word in enumerate(words):
            Label(newWindow, text=word).pack(anchor = W)

    if password.get() != "test":
        Label(tkWindow, text="Wrong password!", fg='red').grid(row=5, column=2)

#window
tkWindow = Tk()
tkWindow.geometry('250x100')
tkWindow.title('Passwords')

#password label and password entry box
passwordLabel = Label(tkWindow,text="Password").grid(row=1, column=0)
password = StringVar()
passwordEntry = Entry(tkWindow, textvariable=password, show='*').grid(row=1, column=2)

validateLogin = partial(validateLogin, password)

#login button
loginButton = Button(tkWindow, text="Login", command=validateLogin).grid(row=4, column=2)

tkWindow.mainloop()
```

The second problem is that the scrollbar is practically useless.  I don't believe that scrollbars natively work on windows/frames in tkinter.  This means that after fixing the original problem, both the Labels and scrollbar will now load, but the scrollbar will do nothing.  [Here's a quick tutorial I found from google that should probably help you to get the scrollbar to work](http://%20https://blog.tecladocode.com/tkinter-scrollable-frames/)