# Tkinter Make PageOne from Mr Bryan Oakley child of Mr. Mikhails' ScrolledWindow

Tags: oop, tkinter, canvas, scrollbar, frame

I´m using this very known script from Mr. Bryan Oakley. My question is: How make class PageOne child of ScrolledWindow  from Mr. Mikhail (https://stackoverflow.com/users/6470235/mikhail-tin). His script is in the question: [Tkinter scrollbar for frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188420/tkinter-scrollbar-for-frame/69564648?noredirect=1#comment122962197_69564648). But I wrote both bellow.

When I try
PageOne = ScrolledWindow(parent=SampleApp) python asks for controller, if I use container, it doesnot recognize it.
If I use PageOne = ScrolledWindow(parent=SampleApp, controller = SampleApp.container)
it says:
SampleApp has no attribute 'container'

I´m very curious about the answer of this puzzle.

Thanks in advance.

```
import tkinter as tk                # python 3
from tkinter import font as tkfont  # python 3
from tkinter import ttk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, ScrolledWindow):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page One",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="ScrolledWindow",
                    command=lambda: controller.show_frame("ScrolledWindow"))
        button1.pack()
        button2.pack()

        
class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))

        button.pack()

class ScrolledWindow(tk.Frame):
    """
    1. Master widget gets scrollbars and a canvas. Scrollbars are connected 
    to canvas scrollregion.

    2. self.scrollwindow is created and inserted into canvas

    Usage Guideline:
    Assign any widgets as children of <ScrolledWindow instance>.scrollwindow
    to get them inserted into canvas

    __init__(self, parent, canv_w = 400, canv_h = 400, *args, **kwargs)
    docstring:
    Parent = master of scrolled window
    canv_w - width of canvas
    canv_h - height of canvas

    """


    def __init__(self, parent, controller, canv_w = 400, canv_h = 400, *args, **kwargs):
        """Parent = master of scrolled window
        canv_w - width of canvas
        canv_h - height of canvas

        """
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.parent = parent
        
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))

        button.pack()
        
        # creating a scrollbars
        self.xscrlbr = ttk.Scrollbar(self.parent, orient = 'horizontal')
        self.xscrlbr.grid(column = 0, row = 1, sticky = 'ew', columnspan = 2)         
        self.yscrlbr = ttk.Scrollbar(self.parent)
        self.yscrlbr.grid(column = 1, row = 0, sticky = 'ns')         
        # creating a canvas
        self.canv = tk.Canvas(self.parent)
        self.canv.config(relief = 'flat',
                            width = 10,
                            heigh = 10, bd = 2)
        # placing a canvas into frame
        self.canv.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = 'nsew')
        # accociating scrollbar comands to canvas scroling
        self.xscrlbr.config(command = self.canv.xview)
        self.yscrlbr.config(command = self.canv.yview)

        # creating a frame to inserto to canvas
        self.scrollwindow = ttk.Frame(self.parent)

        self.canv.create_window(0, 0, window = self.scrollwindow, anchor = 'nw')

        self.canv.config(xscrollcommand = self.xscrlbr.set,
                            yscrollcommand = self.yscrlbr.set,
                            scrollregion = (0, 0, 100, 100))

        self.yscrlbr.lift(self.scrollwindow)        
        self.xscrlbr.lift(self.scrollwindow)
        self.scrollwindow.bind('<Configure>', self._configure_window)  
        self.scrollwindow.bind('<Enter>', self._bound_to_mousewheel)
        self.scrollwindow.bind('<Leave>', self._unbound_to_mousewheel)

        return

    def _bound_to_mousewheel(self, event):
        self.canv.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self._on_mousewheel)   

    def _unbound_to_mousewheel(self, event):
        self.canv.unbind_all("<MouseWheel>") 

    def _on_mousewheel(self, event):
        self.canv.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units")  

    def _configure_window(self, event):
        # update the scrollbars to match the size of the inner frame
        size = (self.scrollwindow.winfo_reqwidth(), self.scrollwindow.winfo_reqheight())
        self.canv.config(scrollregion='0 0 %s %s' % size)
        if self.scrollwindow.winfo_reqwidth() != self.canv.winfo_width():
            # update the canvas's width to fit the inner frame
            self.canv.config(width = self.scrollwindow.winfo_reqwidth())
        if self.scrollwindow.winfo_reqheight() != self.canv.winfo_height():
            # update the canvas's width to fit the inner frame
            self.canv.config(height= self.scrollwindow.winfo_reqheight())
            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of try and error I found a solution:

The Idea is to do a complete class with frame --> canvas --> desired frame outside the SampleApp and send it to the constructor loop:

[image]

This is the code to build a scrolled frame window inside the main class in a loop (after that you can change "Page_with_Scrooll_bar" to "PageOne" as I've asked in question):

```
import tkinter as tk                # python 3
from tkinter import font as tkfont  # python 3
from tkinter import ttk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
       
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo, Page_with_Scroll_bar):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page One",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page two",
                    command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageTwo"))
        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Example with Scrollbar",
                    command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Page_with_Scroll_bar"))
        button1.pack()
        button2.pack()
        button3.pack()

        
class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))

        button.pack()

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 2", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))

        button.pack()


class Page_with_Scroll_bar(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, background="#ffffff")
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)

        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas.create_window((4,4), window=self.frame, anchor="nw",
                                  tags="self.frame")

        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)

        self.populate()
        self.button = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Go to the start page",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))

        self.button.grid(row=102, column=1)
    
    def populate(self):
        '''Put in some fake data'''
        for row in range(100):
            tk.Label(self.frame, text="%s" % row, width=3, borderwidth="1",
                     relief="solid").grid(row=row, column=0)
            t="this is the second column for row %s" %row
            tk.Label(self.frame, text=t).grid(row=row, column=1)

    
    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
        '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))


            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```