# Tkinter, larger windows than desktop

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

To make a very large form, I need tkinter window greater than my desktop screen with a scroll bar. Lower part of the form is disappearing.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('1000x1000')


root.mainloop
```

Thanks

Comment: This is not how its done . you don't add scrollbar to your `desktop` .scrollbar is added to application widow with scrollable canvas/area. so setting a res of `1000X1000` makes no sense if you have a smaller desktop screen. what you are looking for is a window that expands to fit your desktop-screen width/height and then put scrollable child components in it

Comment: Can I add the scroll bar in the frames

Comment: did you search for the same ? if you just type that in google or any search engine you will get lots of links/tutorials/snippets. here is one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873575/how-could-i-get-a-frame-with-a-scrollbar-in-tkinter